# The archive "Xcode_9_beta_4.xip" is damaged and can't be expanded

Tags: xcode, developer-program

My other apps work great. Downloaded directly from the Apple Developer site.

Tried to restore the 'Anywhere' permission in Security already. Restarted already. Downloaded again already.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I just kept deleting and downloading again, and finally it worked. Not the best experience. I think it was the 4th or 5th time.

Comment: Sometimes this happens for no apparent reason (it happened to me multiple times, for different files from multiple websites.

Comment: Don't worry about it.

Comment: Ugh, sigh. Yes. I tried using `curl -C -` to do the downloading, because I didn't trust the browser to download a 7.6 GB file successfully, and of course this happens. Either Apple's download server just sucks (probably more likely), or they've stuck some kind of technological countermeasures in there to frustrate us.